# Why are these two elements overlapping? CSS issue

Tags: html, css, overlap

having a hard time figuring out why these two html elements are overlapping. Below is the HTML and CSS files for the respective elements. I have searched through many threads here but none of the solutions are working. Thanks!

main.css:

```
    #titlesection {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

#contentdiv {
  top: 30%;
  left: 2%;
  width: 97%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

#title {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  height: auto;
}

#titlesubheading {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

#socialmedia {
  width: 97%;
  display: block;
}

#smtable {
  width: 10%;
  float: right;
}

#aboutheader {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: static;
}

#about {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 0px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
}

#abouttext {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  min-height: 140px;
}
```

index.html :

```
<body>
    <section id="titlesection">
      <div id="title">
        Abdullah Rehmat
      </div>
      <div id="titlesubheading">
        Freelance Developer
      </div>
      <div id="socialmedia">
        <table id="smtable">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="a">
                <a href="mailto: rehmat.dev@gmail.com">
                  <img
                    src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/email.png')}}"
                    width="33"
                    height="33"
                  />
                </a>
              </td>
              <td class="a">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/ARehmat20" target="_blank">
                  <img
                    src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/twitter0.svg')}}"
                    width="50"
                    height="50"
                  />
                </a>
              </td>
              <td class="a">
                <a href="https://github.com/10CodeDev" target="_blank">
                  <img
                    src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/github.png')}}"
                    width="30"
                    height="30"
                  />
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div id="contentdiv">
      <div id="aboutheader">
        About:
      </div>
```

Here is an image of the issue. The aboutheader is overlapping the titlesubheading:
[image: image of the two elements overlapping]

Comment: Hi Abdullah. Have a look at your HTML-Sample, it's cut off at the end. With a complete sample, people on SO can help you better.

Comment: Will edit it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have both of those elements as `position: absolute;`. You can fix it by removing. Update your CSS to be this:

**Edit**: For your information as well, position lets you reposition elements within certain contexts. `position: absolute;` positions an element from the top left of the page, or if its parent has `position: relative;` then from that element instead. `position: relative;` repositions something from its initial position.

You then use `top`, `left`, `right`, or `bottom`, to choose how to reposition the item.

```css
#titlesection {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#contentdiv {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 97%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#title {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  height: auto;
}

#titlesubheading {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

#socialmedia {
  width: 97%;
  display: block;
}

#smtable {
  width: 10%;
  float: right;
}

#aboutheader {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: static;
}

#about {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 0px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
}

#abouttext {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  min-height: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ou can use the CSS **position** property in combination with the
>   **z-index** property to overlay an individual div over another div element. The **z-index** property determines the stacking order for
>   positioned elements